# Jquery - Using a modal dialog during select on autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, modal-dialog

I am trying to get the Jquery UI modal dialog to take over after an autocomplete item is selected. I have everything popping up as excepted but there is code being ran after the modal dialog is up. In the end I want to have this dialog popup and react based on the button.

**Select from auto-complete:**

```
        select: function( event, ui ) {
        if(ui.item.squad != '0'){
            console.info('popup');
            var choice=null;

            $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height:140,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Cancel: function() {
                        choice = false;
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    "Move Shooter": function() {
                        choice = true;
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                    }
                }
            });
            if(!choice){
                console.info($(this));
                $(this).text("");
                $(this).val("");
                $(this).attr("name", "");
                $(this).attr("value", "");
                console.info("false");
                return;
            }
        }
```

Most of the code has been taken from jquery ui [here.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

When I run this code I thought it would stop running code until a button was pressed but as you can see [here](http://practiscore.com/test.php) the line that prints false to the console is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code wont work as it will execute that entire block and return. What you want todo is define a function that is executed once the user has made their choice. Essentially you would do this by moving the `if` statement you have under the dialog code to its own function and then call this function as part of your button handler code.

Example:

Define the callback somewhere:

```
function handleDialogResponse(choice) {
    if(!choice){
        console.info($(this));
        $(this).text("");
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).attr("name", "");
        $(this).attr("value", "");
        console.info("false");
    }
}
```

Then change your dialog button code to something like this:

```
buttons: {
    Cancel: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );

        handleDialogResponse(false);
    },
    "Move Shooter": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );

        handleDialogResponse(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: And your my hero. Thanks for the help